# Run a job during a SVN commit

Tags: java, svn, task

which is the best way to integrate a task that should be done on a svn server when a specific repository receives a commit?

Brief explanation: I would like to build a JAR application from a java project that is actually maintained on a personal SVN server and I would like to do it in a fully automatic way.

For now I'm not using any building tool (eg ANT) so a simple but functional solution would be preferred..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a post-commit [Repository Hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks).

Of course a CI system such as [Jenkins](http://www.jenkinsci.org) will do that for you, and much more.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) for project build (test and distributive creation).

There is a [big amount of Continuous Integration tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Software).